# How to build this macro

Tags: c++, c

The following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 100
#define tam atoi(getenv("tam"))
#if tam > 0
#endif
```

give this error

testec99.c:6:17: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #define tam atoi(getenv("tam"))
                 ^
testec99.c:7:5: note: in expansion of macro 'tam'
 #if tam > 0

But if i remove the #if , it runs correctly if "tam" is not dimension of an array. So i need to get the N value of a environment variable. There's any way to contour this problem?

Answer (score 4):

The preprocessor runs at compile time (somehow even before it).

So

```
#if tam > 0
```

doesn't evaluate the result of

```
atoi(getenv("tam"))
```

but just does a textual replacement.

The evaluated directive

```
 #if atoi(getenv("tam"))> 0
```

doesn't makes sense for the preprocessor, hence the error message.

`getenv()` is meant to be evaluated at runtime. The preprocessor won't actually do what you seem to want to achieve here.

---

> *"There's any way to contour this problem?"*

Yes, you may use the compiler's `-D` option to resolve the `$tam` environment value instead (e.g. for GCC toolchain):

```
g++ -Dtam=$tam ...
```

Comment: but it is weird, if i don't try to create an array of size tam and just print value of tam , it works. Am i missing something?

Comment: @JoãoPauloAndrade _"Am i missing something?"_ Yes, seriously, `#if tam > 0` is executed at compile time, while something like `cout << tam << endl;` expands to `cout << atoi(getenv("tam")) << endl;` and is executed at runtime.